# Unity menu bar into title bar integration stopped working for gnome-terminal

Tags: unity, gnome-terminal, menu, menu-bar

Today when I started `gnome-terminal`, the menu bar was not integrated into the title bar as usually. Only the **Terminal** menu point is correctly integrated, all others show up in a separate menu bar.

The Unity setting for that seems still correct and it works also e.g. for Firefox and others.

[image]

If I untick the <kbd>Show Menubar</kbd> option, I lose the menu entirely, just the **Terminal** menu point is still there and still correctly integrated into the title bar. All other menu points are gone.

[image]

Right-clicking the title bar just brings the normal context menu:

[image]

This is not an issue when operating on the guest account! It works perfectly well there and shows all menu points correctly integrated into either the title bar or the panel, depending on the setting.

What is the problem here and how can I fix the menu-into-title-bar-integration again?

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 with Unity 7.3.2 and gnome-terminal 3.16.2-1ubuntu4.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking the title bar? I *believe* that brings up the relevant option, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @kos Nothing unusual when right-clicking the title bar... See my edit (added 3rd picture), please.

Comment: Is this option enabled? http://cdn5.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/03_in_the_windows_title_bar.png

Comment: @kos Yes, it is. I just checked it and set it to "menu bar" and back to "window's title bar" again. It did not change anything, but it would only have moved the menu from the window's title bar to the panel anyway. It should not toggle showing a separate menu bar.

Comment: It seems broken then. Is reinstalling `gnome-terminal` an option?

Comment: @kos I just found out that it's working on the guest account without any problems. That's an argument against hoping that reinstalling will fix it, right?

Comment: Yes, and thinking about it again maybe it would have been an overkill regardless. New profile?

Comment: @kos "new profile" sounds definitely like much more work than reinstalling that package... I hate making new profiles. :P

Comment: Just a plain default one, just to see if that fixes it. If it does yeah, you'll have to copy the settings from the broken one :D

Comment: @kos Don't ask me why, but the default error solving method for Windows systems (REBOOT) did the trick... :P

Comment: Huh. Well, it happens :D

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why and appreciate any other answer that might shed some more light on this, but I could solve this problem simply...

**... by rebooting!**

Maybe logging out and back in or restarting the Unity desktop environment would have solved it as well, I can't tell you because I did not try.